# Revision History Tortoise Hg

Tags: tortoisehg, revision-history

I know that it is possible to view the revision history of a single file in Tortoise Hg. However, I would like to view the revision history within a certain directory. Is this possible with TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseHG Workbench - Main menu - `View` - `Filter Toolbar`

Write revset condition into listbox, enable "Filter" checkbox

For path-based revset you have to use `file()` function with needed directory [pattern](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#file-name-patterns)

[image: Filtered Log]

PS: For CLI this log can be built even faster

`hg log -r "file('lang/UTF-8/*')"` - only *this* dir

`hg log -r "file('lang/**')"` - *this* dir *with subdirs*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TortoiseHg on Windows, you can navigate to the parent directory of the directory you are interested in, click on the directory's entry, select TortoiseHg from its context menu and then click on "Revision History"

Comment: Icon overlays is only icons overlays - you can use Revision History in any case

Comment: Merci, @lazy-badger. I have fixed my response.

Comment: Oh I did not know this!! I was selecting inside a blank space inside the desired directory instead of the directory itself.. thanks!